# seo friendly url with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to introduce seo friendly url in my site. I would like to change the url: http://www.example.com/usa/searched-page.php?ad-id=57

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^searched-page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ searched-page.php?ad_id=$1
```

But the code is not working. I can not find out where I am going wrong. Please..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming mod-rewrite is on and you are using below rule in usa directory, try as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^searched-page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ searched-page.php?ad-id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what is the error? One more thing I've edited the rule because there is an '-'in between ad&id instead of '_' please check now.

Comment: Did you tried once again as I mentioned in comment and also your url is working without rewrite?

Comment: What is the url in brower you are trying?

Comment: in both ie and firefox not working. I think there is some problem in htaccess file.

Comment: I am asking for url you are typing in browser can you show me?

Comment: Actually the site is under construction. http://www.freenetadvertise.com/united-states/searched_page.php?ad_id=567

Comment: Try this it is working `http://www.freenetadvertise.com/united-states/searched_page/567/` as per your requirement. just copy paste the link and put it in url bar.